# Applied for position A, the employee replied for position B? How to deal with the situtation

Tags: contracts, communication, interview

I am in a situation: I applied for iOS developer, but then the employer sent me an email says:

> Thanks for apply for PHP position. Do you have time  for an
>   interview...blah.

What should I response in this situation? Are they testing me?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably just a honest mistake - so tell them you applied for the iOS position.

You really have no alternative; if you don't tell them, do you plan attempting to successfully handle a PHP interview?

Regardless of what happens, they WILL find out that a mistake was made - and it will reflect badly on you not correcting it as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank a lot. I just told them what I applied for and they corrected it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what "applying" and "interviews" have to do with freelancing.... but....

Realize that *most* people in charge of the first round of hiring choices (Human relations officers/HR) have *no idea* what the actual skills for a position are. They are merely reading off of a piece of paper or email. The HR department weeds out the completely undesirable candidates, *then* the interviews involve someone that *knows* the skills you'll need.

I'd just reply back...

> Hi X,
>
> I was seeking the position of an iOS developer. I was not applying for a PHP development position.
>
> I would love an opportunity to interview. However, I'd hate to waste your time if I've mistakenly applied for the incorrect position.
>
> I'm happy to schedule an interview if you are seeking an iOS developer.

Or something along those lines. Don't interview for a position you aren't qualified for, or you don't even want. Clarify the mistake first.